# in F#, what is the precedence of the forward composition operator, relatively to the pipe forward operator?

Tags: f#

What is the precedence of the forward composition operator `|>` in F#, relatively to the pipe forward operator `>>` ?

I did find the piece of the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#operator-precedence) relative to precedence of operators but there's not mention of `>>` nor `|>` in the table.

I'd like to understand where in the docs or specs the info can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have the same precedence, as described by this row in the linked table:

> `<op, >op, =, |op, &op, &, $`

`|>` is an instance of `|op` and `>>` is an instance of `>op`, where "*op* can be any valid (possibly empty) sequence of operator characters, either built-in or user-defined".

For example, `a >> b |> c >> d |> e` is the same as `(((a >> b) |> c) >> d) |> e`, since the operators are left-associative.